# Don't understand this hash map increment syntax

Tags: java, hashmap

h is a Hash Map (generic type Character, Integer).
The first example works, but the second example throws a wrong result (doesn't increment properly). Why?

correct

```
if (h.containsKey(c)) {
        h.put(c, h.get(c)+1);
}
else {
        h.put(c, 1);
}
```

wrong

```
if (h.containsKey(c)) {
        int value = h.get(c);
        h.put(c, value++);
}
else {
        h.put(c, 1);
}
```

Comment: Using ++value will work fine.
That's because value++ increments its value after it is sent to h.put()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using post-increment, your variable is passed to the function and only after that  incremented

```
 h.put(c, ++value);
```

this is the syntax for pre-increment which increments the the variable before passing it to the `get` call

Answer (score 2):

You're really misusing `++` here. You don't want to increment the variable, you just want to use its value plus one:

```
h.pus(c, value + 1)
```

Note that `value++` will increment `value` but return its *original* value, which is why you're seeing different results.

While using `++value` resolves the issue as well, it's still a misuse of `++`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are putting the same value for key `c` to your `hashmap` because `value++` will evaluate after function `put` was executed.

```
if (h.containsKey(c)) {
        int value = h.get(c);
        h.put(c, value++); // should be h.put(c,++value) or h.put(c,value+1)
}
else {
        h.put(c, 1);
}
```

try to use `++value` instead of `value+1`

In java there are two types of incrementing functions one is `postfix` and `prefix`.

postfix -  `value++` wll return `value` and the do increment operation

prefix -  `++value` will do increment operation and then return incremented value

the same story is with decrementation

[more details](http://www.freejavaguide.com/increment_decrement_operators.htm)

Answer (score 0):

With `value++` you are assigning to `value` after you pass it to the function thus the `value` variable used will be the `value` variable before the increment.

Answer (score 0):

The `preIncrement (++x)` and `postIncrement (x++)` are different.
And you are using the second one, which will change the value of `x` right after executing the instruction. 
So in `h.put(c, value++);` line, you are putting the `value` to the `h` hashmap, and then increasing its value.

But as you want to add the `value + 1` to the hashmap, you have to write it like this:

```
h.put(c, ++value);
```

So it increases the `value` first, and then puts it in the HashMap.